# How to get "HTTPS" link and How to convert epub to txt in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, epub

I want to convert epub to txt.
I first do epub to xhtml by zipfile.
and then i try to convert xhtml to epub by beautifulsoup.

However, there is a problem because of local file name.
An example, MY xhtml file name is "C:\Users\abc.xhtml", not "HTTPS".
So beautifulsoup isn't working.

How can i solve this?

```
'''
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Users\\abc.epub')
zf.extractall('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder')
'''
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "C:\\Users\\abc.xhtml"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.text)
```

Comment: Your question is basically: "How to convert .epub to txt?" 
You don't specify why you would need or want additional complexity or functionality from the `bs4` library. I gave you the answer to your question, so why accept an answer that is more complex? Easy is better than complex, according to the Zen of Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need BeautifulSoup for the extraction.

You can convert .epub files to text using the `epub-conversion` package, installable from PyPi:

```
pip install epub-conversion
```

Now it's a simple task to extract the text from an epub archive:

#### Line-by-line:

```py
from epub_conversion.utils import open_book, convert_epub_to_lines

book = open_book("some_file.epub")

lines = convert_epub_to_lines(book)
```

Now, as in your question you can print it as a whole or choose to process each line:

```py
print(lines)

# or traverse each line
for line in lines:
    print(line) # Or do something completely different
```

Comment: Sorry, i see this anwser now.
But i have some problems.
First, "xml_cleaner" error.
I solve this problem by using "xml-cleaner" instead of "xml_cleaner".
Is it correct?

Also, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'opf'.
How can i solve it?

Comment: @rut If you agree to that my answer is the better way than messing with BS, [mark my answer as the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and I'll tell you!  Kidding, but **it would be appreciated**! I'll explain this when I'm back from work and have more time!

Comment: @rut Can you paste the code somewhere? Either update your question or use a Gist and link to it here?

Answer (score 0):

The `BeautifulSoup` constructor expects the actual contents of a html file, not a url. Try this:

```
with open(html) as f:
    contents = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoupd(contents, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Question says: he / she already has an .epub file, and wants to get the text. 
Why bother with first using `zipfile` for unpacking, then `bs4` and `lxml`, when all you need is the text from the .epub? See my answer for a simpler solution.

Comment: Easy is better than complex. -- Zen of Python. My solution is simpler and easier.

Comment: Relax, it's not a competition

Comment: To me it is! 